# I'm having a ton of trouble installing a process manager for my Rails app

Tags: monit

After a long time wasted trying to get Bluepill to work for process management, I'm trying to get monit set up.  I'm not a Sys Admin but know my way around *nix systems.  I'm a bit stumped here.

When I run the command to restart all monit processes I get this output:

```
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro$ sudo monit restart all
'delayed_job' trying to restart
'delayed_job' start: /usr/bin/env
delayed_job: process with pid 16901 started.
'delayed_job' failed to start
'george' trying to restart
```

However the process is not running when I check with PS.  Not to mention it's not doing what it's supposed to so I'm pretty sure it's not working.

Then when I try to reload monit I get this:

```
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro$ sudo monit reload     
Reinitializing monit daemon
monit: No daemon process found
```

even though I have a conf:

```
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro$ ls /etc/monit/conf.d/            
george.conf
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old question, but I'm documenting my (potential) answer for future Googlers.

What worked for me was: `sudo service monit start`

There's also a decent blog post on this: [Solve monit: error connecting to the monit daemon](http://yoodey.com/solve-monit-error-connecting-monit-daemon)

This still might give you an error about not being able to connect to the server. Apparently monit talks to the monit daemon essentially over an HTTP connection, and you need to configure what HTTP ports monit should use (and from what source it should allow these connections to happen on).

Add these lines to your monitrc:

You need to add following to monitrc (or whatever port number and allow requirements make sense in your situation) :

```
set httpd port 2812
allow localhost
```

[Source (for the HTTP information): the monit mailing list, 2009](http://www.mail-archive.com/monit-general@nongnu.org/msg02887.html)